# Curl Login to website which javascript(or jquery) login box

Tags: php, curl

I have a script which logs into a website and im trying to update it to log into this other website but they have a scripted login box, not sure if its jquery/javascript or something but my usual script isnt working.

This is the site: http://uploaded.net, You click Login along the bottom and it pops up a little box.

The action of the form is `action="io/login"`

This is the script ive used in the past which worked for standard HTML login boxes.

```
$username="xxxxx"; 
$userpass="xxxxx"; 
$url="http://uploaded.net/#login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 


$postdata = "id=".$username."&pw=".$userpass."";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$headers  = array();

$headers[] = 'application/xhtml+voice+xml;version=1.2, application/x-xhtml+voice+xml;version=1.2, text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Anyone have an idea what i can do to login to this website using cURL?

Many Thanks

Comment: I've not looked at that page specifically, but try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18166859/2908724

Comment: thats not PHP is it ? :(

Comment: No. AFAIK, if you need Javascript interaction, you're going to need a Javascript engine -- like node.js in that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing $url to

```
     $url="http://uploaded.net/io/login";
```

is the action of the form.

I've tested it and obtained an

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 19:00:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 41
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"err":"User and password do not match!"}

I think it's better for you taking out

```
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

in order to get rid of headers in responses and make processing results step easier

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! i tried changing the URL to what you said and removing the line you mentioned but it dosen't seem to set the cookie in cookie.php and i have it to echo $result; but nothing is returned with you URL you suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: your code seems to work fine; it returns auth results (a failure, of course) and saves data in cookies.txt. Try close curl connection and/or check write permissions of the working directory.

Comment: Im running it on my PC, I used the same script with another login and it worked perfectly. The cookie.txt isnt read only so im assuming thats writeable? I never did anything special on my other script. I get a similar message to you but nothing goes into the cookie.txt file.

Comment: ok i added curl_close($ch); and it worked? Is that seriously why it wasn't working before :S Many thanks for your help.